# Find URL request origin in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I see a url `hxxp//vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/product_designs/grey.jpg` failed call `i.e 404` when access [this](http://vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/) **(which I inherited the code from a previous developer)** when I open console in chrome. I am curious how is the url called.

If I go to the network tab in chrome it says "others" as initiator. I just need to know what is requesting that url and how is that happening. I inherited the code from a previous developer and I have hard time finding and fixing the `404 issue`.

I also don't know how to figure out similar cases where the initiator is jquery. `eg. hxxp//vps100011.vps.ovh.ca/images/natural.jpg`

If in anyway the question can be helpful to other beginners like me please let me know how to rephrase in a better way.

Thank you in advance,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a general answer to this. Given a web-page, you can idnetify main technolgies that are used by it. And then you need to understand the main scripts the page is laoding and relying on.

In other words, some of the urls are created and/or requested by the JS scripts so unless you understand the code and spend sometime on it, you may not be able to find out the origin of each url request/ajax call using the development tools like the one in chrome.

Overall, you need to have general idea of how main web technolgoies are working so that you can follow the url requests easily in practice.

I hope it helps.